# 'System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog' is a type not a namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

It is possible that I'm missing something very obvious but now I can not see now. I have the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and I have the next `using` classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
```

But the compiler always give to me the next error:

> **error CS0138**: A using namespace directive can only be applied to
>   namespaces; 'System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog' is a type not a
>   namespace

Comment: The error message is quite explicit, I don't think it really needs an extra explanation...

Comment: Yes, I think I will delete the question.

Comment: I spy java brain damage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot do

```
using System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
```

as it *is* a type and not a namespace. The namespace it belongs to is `System.Windows.Forms`. Remove this line and if you want to instantiate a `FolderBrowserDialog` and just make sure you have the line

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and make a `FolderBrowserDialog` like so:

```
var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
```

---

All this is in contrast to Java, where you *import types* not *use namespaces*, which is where you may be going wrong - in Java you would do something like:

```
import System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
```

and then be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The `using` directive imports namespaces, not types.

Once you import `System.Windows.Forms`, you can use all of the types inside of it, including `FolderBrowserDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog is not a namespace but rather a class that is part of the namespace [System.Windows.Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k50ex0x9.aspx).

The *.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog is a class located within that namespace. [Here is an example of how it should be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5db6b0zy.aspx). (example is at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

That's because it IS a type, not a namespace.  You don't reference the types in the using statements, only the namespaces.  This isn't Java.

Answer (score 0):

System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog is a class, is'nt a namespace to using it, clear that line.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're trying to import FolderBrowserDialog but it's actually an object.  To use it you remove:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog;
```

And instead reference is by creating an object like this...

```
FolderBrowserDialog x = new FolderBrowserDialog();
```