# Error while adding namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net

After lot's of effort and searching, I have decided to ask the question. I have a dll which I have added in my project and after adding namespace it shows error i.e.,

> Error 1   A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces;
>   'Captcha' is a type not a namespace

[image]

When I have added this dll to other project it works fine but don't know what's happening in this project. I have cleaned the solution, added the dll and reference again but still the same error.

**Edit:-** ddl

[image]

After removing the dll I have typed cap but Intellisense shows nothing regarding captcha.
[image]

Comment: Are you using same version of VS in both the cases?

Comment: Yes, both have same version

Comment: What  happens if you remove the dll and use `Captcha`. What I'm getting at is; maybe there's another definition of Captcha that's conflicting?

Comment: This error occurs. Error 4 The type or namespace name 'Captcha' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Is there any case that you have `Captcha` cs file that is conflicting?

Comment: And what happens when you write `Captcha.Captcha` without any using statements? Does it exist?

Comment: I have but I have renamed it but same result

Comment: @Rob captcha.captcha shows error.

Comment: just becasue the dll name is captcha doesn't mean it's namespace is the same, use object browser, or type global:: so intelisense show all available namespaces to you, and nice you put DLL there, but did you made a reference to it?

Comment: @deadManN if it's namespace isn't captcha that how come it shows it's classes. Please see the image and I already mentioned about adding the reference. Well it's namespace is captcha. I will attach image regarding this.

Comment: Do you have a class called `Captcha` too?

Comment: And I already mentioned that it's working fine in other project.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel no there is no class captcha

Comment: some times it happen when there are both a namespace and a type with same name not on using,...
your solution name is "Captcha" and your project name too, i Assume default namespace in your project is "Captcha" too, so classes create by your project use the same namespace, maybe somethings wrong with that... (as namespace it self is re definable)

Comment: @deadManN My project don't have namespace named captcha. If it is so then what rob told me would have worked as he told me to remove the dll and then type namespace captcha.

Comment: i think i'm finished at this point :-s good luck

Comment: Maybe there is a class/delegate/struct somewhere called `Capcha`? Remove the assembly reference and try to use `Captcha c = new Captcha()` and see what happens. Maybe there is a type hiding somewhere.

Comment: already tried after suggestion given by rob

Comment: without adding the using statement - if you write Captcha.RandCode o = new Captcha.RandCode(). Is this working?

Comment: @Taleeb no, it's not working. Same error persist.

Comment: It could be that you have something cached somewhere. Try deleting `bin` and `obj` folders and let the Visual Studio regenerate them on the next build.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic after suggesting by you, I have tried but same result.

Comment: Are you targeting the same .NET Framework version in both solutions?

Comment: yup same framework 4.0

Comment: try to rename Captcha dll to CaptchaNamespace and then see what happens

Comment: @AdrianStanculescu you mean to say to renaming the dll?

Comment: @Litisqe Kumar yes. because you have a dll and a class with same name. or rename the captcha class.

Comment: you are referring to class or namespace ?

Comment: you have a class and a namespace with same name. or rename namespace into CaptchaNamespace or rename class into CaptchaClass. Try one or both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87344/discussion-between-adrian-stanculescu-and-litisqe-kumar).

Comment: I don't have a class with same namespace. Nor any class is named to captcha

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173398/system-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-is-a-type-not-a-namespace)

Comment: Another thing which you can try is to change the namespace (or is it a 3rd party control?)

Comment: Is your problem solved or does it still persists?

Comment: @Meghaa yes, problem still persists

Comment: Is it possible for you to place sample of your solution file somewhere and we can try and run it on our side. I am asking this because in the past someone has similar problems but in his case the issue was that the dll he had downloaded was somehow corrupt. But since in your case ir works in some projects iI would assume your dll is fine

Comment: Yup my dll is fine as it's not a third party dll. So, issue might resides in my project. So, I am just trying to make a new project and add all the dll and other relevant pages one by one. So, that I can catch the issue.

Answer (score 1):

even after reading the comments, I'm pretty sure that you have a type called Captcha hiding somewhere.

You could try the object explorer, or checking inside the other dlls you have referenced (the fact that Captcha.dll works for other projects could hint you about which dll to check first).

But the message VS is giving you is pretty clear: you DO HAVE a type Captcha somewhere.
I found that this is a case in which Intellisense keeps working even if the compiler is complaining.

I hope to put you in the right track.

Good luck!

Edit: just to clarify. A type can be a class, a struct or an enum.

Edit2: I just noticed you have the bin folder included in your project. Well, that is usually a really bad idea. The bin folder should be excluded from the project (right click, then "Exclude folder from project"). Then you should check your references. Just to be sure, remove all of them, and clean empty the bin folder too. Then reference the dlls through nuget or browsing to a lib folder. If you have files in the bin folder, "bad things do happen".

Comment: I have removed the captcha.dll and then try to type captcha but Intellisense shows nothing regarding captcha. Please see the image I have just uploaded.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Try to use the object explorer and find if some other Captcha class or something exists in your other dlls. Or, type Captcha and then press <ctrl+.> . If there is a Captcha type, it should show up as an "include corresponding namespace" message.

Comment: Oh, and do the "remove and add" references I described in my second edit. The bin folder can really mess up your references.